# How can I deal with this code error which happens in my custom layer in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I want to make a custom layer in Keras. 
In this example, I use a variable to multiply the tensor, but i get the error which is

> in /keras/engine/training_arrays.py, line 304, in predict_loop
>       outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (36) into shape (2).

Actually i have check this file, but i get nothing. Is there some wrong in my custom layer?

```
#the definition of mylayer.


 from keras import backend as K
 import keras
 from keras.engine.topology import Layer

class mylayer(Layer):
def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    super(mylayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel',
                                  shape=(1,),dtype='float32',trainable=True,initializer='uniform')
    super(mylayer, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    return self.kernel * inputs[0]
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1])


#the test of mylayer.

from mylayer import mylayer
from tensorflow import keras as K
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model

x_train = np.random.random((2, 3, 4, 3))
y_train = np.random.random((2, 36))
print(x_train)

x = Input(shape=(3, 4, 3))
y = Flatten()(x)
output = mylayer((36, ))(y)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=output)

model.summary()

 model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2)

hist = model.predict(x_train,batch_size=2)

print(hist)

print(model.get_layer(index=1).get_weights())


#So is there some wrong in my custom error?
```

Especially, when i train this net, it's ok,but when i try to use "prdict", it's wrong.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback as code-formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shape of `self.kernel * inputs[0]` is `(36,)`, but your expectation is `(?,36)`. Change it:

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    return self.kernel * inputs
```

If you want to output the weight of `mylayer`, you should set `index=2`.